# Error 1004: Unable to Get CountIf Property

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to search a range of named cells to see if there are any cells that contain a number greater than zero.  Here is the code I currently have:

```
Dim YTDclauses As Boolean
Dim ytdrng As Range

Set ytdrng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("z1AY:z1BB,z1BG:z1BJ")

'Employer 1
If Sheet1.[z1AG] = "No" And WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ytdrng, ">0") = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Works!"
Else
    MsgBox "Does Not Work"
End If
```

I'm getting an error back as "Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the CountIfs property of the WorksheetFunction class".  By looking at other questions, I think it might be a syntax error with how I'm setting ytdrng, but I've tried many ways of naming it differently to no avail.  Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Note: Sheet1 is named "Main Checklist" - I also tried using that in the setting of ytdrng, but got the same error.

Comment: that means that the object `WorksheetFunction` does not have a `CountIf` method/property ... or it means that `WorksheetFunction` is not an object that VBA knows about  .... i think that you want `application.worksheetfunction.countif`

Comment: I added the "application.", but am getting the same error.

Comment: You cannot use COUNTIF on a disconnected range.

Comment: Does the equivalent Excel formula work? If not, why do you expect the equivalent VBA code to?

Comment: Ah, I see - thanks @ScottCraner!

Comment: Good point - I don't know much about using formulas (kind of silly for learning VBA, I know), so hadn't compared the VBA code to an Excel formula.  Thanks for that feedback @Mat'sMug

Comment: With a multi-area range you could loop over the areas and sum the counts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@ScottCraner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner) has stated, you cannot do a `countif` on a split range. You can modify the routine slightly to implement a `countif` by looping over each cell in the range:

```
Dim YTDclauses As Boolean
Dim ytdrng As Range
Dim SRCountif As Long
Dim cel As Object

Set ytdrng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("z1AY:z1BB,z1BG:z1BJ")

SRCountif = 0
For Each cel In ytdrng.Cells
    If cel.Value > 0 Then SRCountif = SRCountif + 1
Next

'Employer 1
If Sheet1.[z1AG] = "No" And SRCountif = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Works!"
Else
    MsgBox "Does Not Work"
End If
```

(The variable SRCountif is meant to mean **S**plit**R**ange**Countif**)
Note that as it is comparing the value to numeric 0, Exec takes any text as greater than 0, so you may want to adjust the test if there is a chance of any text in your range.

Comment: That's a really good idea.  I ended up just splitting it into two different ranges and doing CountIf separately, but your answer helped with my conceptual knowledge, as I'm just starting out with VBA.  Thanks!